# Getting a 'RuntimeWarning: coroutine 'function1' was never awaited' error within my Python Discord bot

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

I've spent hours reading similar questions and finding other ways around this problem. I'm trying to create a Discord bot that sends a message to a channel every x amount of time, but I keep getting this error:

**'RuntimeWarning: coroutine 'function1' was never awaited
  self._run_job(job)'**

```
import discord,random,asyncio,os
from discord.ext import commands, tasks
from datetime import datetime
import schedule
import time


token = 'xxxx'


bot = discord.Client
bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix='.')

@bot.event
async def on_ready():
    print('Logged in as')
    print(bot.user.name)
    print(bot.user.id)
    print('-'*80)


async def function1():
    channel = bot.get_channel(656805505804533761)
    await channel.send('test')
    print('test')
    await asyncio.sleep(1)

schedule.every(1).second.do(function1)

while True:
    schedule.run_pending()


bot.run(token)
```

Answer (score 0):

This is because the schedule library that you're using doesn't support coroutines.
Instead, you can use [`create_task`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-eventloop.html#asyncio.loop.create_task) with an event loop to create a background task.

For an example of that with discord.py, see https://github.com/Rapptz/discord.py/blob/master/examples/background_task.py.

Alternatively, you can also use [discord.py's tasks extension](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ext/tasks/index.html), which you seem to already be importing.

Comment: The github example dose not seem to work, nothing is outputted. I copied the example but with my token and server ID just to test it, and nothing happens.

Comment: It uses [`Client.get_channel`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.Client.get_channel) to get the channel to send it to, so you need to use a channel ID.